# SQL 2012 - SSMS- import wizard fails import of excel table - memory corrupt?

Tags: sql-server, import-from-excel

After installing Microsoft Office Viewer (Word and Excel) , the import wizard in the SQL Server Management Studio of the SQL server (12.05.500) returns the following error on trying to import an excel table. What can I do, where to look how to resolve the issue? I am not that familiar....

===================================

This wizard will close because it encountered the following error: (Microsoft SQL Server)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=12.0.5000.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardFrameworkErrorSR&EvtID=UncaughtException&LinkId=20476

===================================

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (System.Data)

---

> Program Location:

```
at System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper.InitializeAndCreateSession(OleDbConnectionString constr, SessionWrapper& sessionWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.DTSWizard.GetOpenedConnection(WizardInputs wizardInputs, String connEntryName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.Step1.OnLeavePage(LeavePageEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardPage.RaiseLeavePage(WizardButton button)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardForm.NextPage(WizardPage nextPage)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardForm.Next_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: By the way, the link "For help" is not giving any answer !!

Comment: Excel file is readable\writable ? This might causing issue, just check ...

Comment: Or you left the file open somewhere in the background :)

Comment: Excel file works fine and is not open elswhere; All types of excel sheets are involved (xls, xlsx, xlsm, etc...) and no mather how big the volume.

Comment: Hmmmm....it takes time to get an answer to my question. As this is my first question ever, i am wondering if I did something wrong (Tag's ?)...any suggestions, someone?